# Hikari CP SSL Exception closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, hikaricp, amazon-aurora

Since switching from Tomcat CP (spring boot 1 default) to Hikari (spring boot 2 default) we've started seeing many instances of:

```
EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:



** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:645)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:624)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.quit(NativeProtocol.java:1312)
    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.quit(NativeSession.java:182)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:1750)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:720)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.quietlyCloseConnection(PoolBase.java:135)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.lambda$closeConnection$1(HikariPool.java:441)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

## Environment

- Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE
- Java 11
- mysql-connector-java 8.0.13
- HikariCP 3.2.0

Database:

- RDS Aurora MySql 5.7.12 (default param group)

## Configuration (Spring Boot)

Settings:

```
spring.datasource.hikari.transactionIsolation=TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ

spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=10

spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=5000

spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=900000
spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout=1000
```

Is there a setting which I'm missing, perhaps my idle times should be set much lower?

We have not (yet) experienced any obvious bad side effects of this, i.e. the application appears to continue running without issue, but this stacktrace appears frequently (perhaps every 4 seconds.

## Database Settings

If I connect to mysql via the cli and run `show variables;` and grep for timeout related values, I see:

```
| connect_timeout                                          | 10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| delayed_insert_timeout                                   | 300                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| have_statement_timeout                                   | YES                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout                              | 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout                                 | 50                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout                               | OFF                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| interactive_timeout                                      | 28800                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| lock_wait_timeout                                        | 31536000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| net_read_timeout                                         | 30                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| net_write_timeout                                        | 60                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout                                   | 31536000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| slave_net_timeout                                        | 60                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| wait_timeout                                             | 28800                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
```

Comment: see related https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/1268

Comment: Thanks, I have now found a bug report in the connector that seems related to this: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93590

Comment: @David After reading that bug report, was you actually able to fix this issue?

Comment: So far no, I'm waiting for this PR (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/pull/32) to be merged and the new version of the connector to be released and then I'll update. For now my logs are filled with horrific endless "errors" day and night. If you find a way please do let me know too :P

Comment: @David so the "fix" was released in mysql-connector v8.0.16 - but it still didn't fix those exceptions for me. Did it work for you?

Comment: I am upgrading this morning as I was using this dependency via spring boot. I think they released 2.1.5 yesterday https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/releases/tag/v2.1.5.RELEASE which includes the update to 8.0.16. Hope to deploy later today and see if this works well.

Comment: The upgrade to spring boot 2.1.5 which included mysql-connector v8.0.16 did the job for me.

Comment: I'm using Java 14, spring boot 2.2.6, mysql-connector v8.0.16 . i see the same error. is it solved somehow?

Comment: @David, upgrading to Spring Boot 2.1.18.RELEASE (with jdk 11) fixed my problem.